# Passing environment variables to Grafana Dashboard JSON file

Tags: json, grafana, grafana-variable

I have a Dockerized instance of Grafana dashboard (with all relevant files) in the git repo, which is connected to the CI/CD pipeline. The dashboard uses Google BigQuery as the data source; it uses queries to display results on the panels. The application is deployed on the cloud and it's running as desired.

However, I want to introduce flexibility in the dashboard's JSON file by using environment variables. For example, rather than using static query like  `SELECT * FROM my_project.my_dataset.my_table`, I want to **pass env variables in the query** as `SELECT * FROM ${project_name}.${dataset_name}.${table_name}`.

The limitation is that **I cannot use any programming language**(such as Python's string formatting).

I have tried `SELECT * FROM ${project_name}.${dataset_name}.${table_name}`, but as per my knowledge, JSON does not automatically insert values into the variables on its own (unlike YAML file).